# How to change cron expression in CronTrigger (quartz 2.2, spring 4.1)

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm a bit stuck migrating to latest quartz 2.2 and spring 4.1... Here's a cron trigger, I omit the job and other fluff for clarity:

```
...
       <bean id="timeSyncTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
         <property name="jobDetail" ref="timeSyncJob"/>
         <property name="startDelay" value="10000"/>
         <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 1 * * ? *"/>
       </bean>
...
```

Now, I need to change its *cronExpression* at run time, and it's not as simple as I thought. I can't reference the bean and change the property because its a factory giving *CronTrigger* interface which in turn doesn't have *setCronExpression* method any longer, it has become immutable. Before I could simply fish out a trigger from the context and set its new cron expression. It worked very well for many years, until the upgrade become unavoidable.

So, how do we accomplish this simple task today? Totally lost in documentations and versions.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the [CronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerFactoryBean.html#setCronExpression-java.lang.String-) method work?

Comment: agh.., that was a silly question, of course the  CronTriggerFactoryBean returns the CronTriggerImpl which does have setCronExpression(). I got confused with CronTrigger interface which doesn't allow setCronExpression. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Dima Did this indeed work for you? The `CronTriggerFactoryBean` seems not prepared for modifiying the cronExpression. It might be on purpose that the CronTrigger interface hasn't got `setCronExpression`. `CronTriggerImpl.setCronExpression` has no effect either, istn't it?

Comment: @Markus Yes, I am doing pretty much the same what you suggested, with slight variation: 

StdScheduler factory = (StdScheduler)context.getBean("schedulerFactory");
CronTriggerImpl trigger = context.getBean(triggerName, CronTriggerImpl.class);
trigger.setCronExpression(expression);
Date date = factory.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the `CronTriggerFactoryBean` you probably have a `SchedulerFactoryBean`, which provides access to the Quartz scheduler as well as the CronTrigger. The Quartz scheduler allows you to reschedule a job with a new/modified trigger:

```
@Autowired private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;
...
public void rescheduleCronJob() {

    String newCronExpression = "..."; // the desired cron expression

    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("timeSyncTrigger");
    CronTriggerImpl trigger = (CronTriggerImpl) scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
    trigger.setCronExpression(newCronExpression );
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger);
}
```