# How to run method/function after every 2 minutes upto 10 minutes in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, timer

I tried to run method/function after every 2 minutes upto 10 minutes using thread but It was taking lot of resources which can slow down the server.

I want achieve somthing like this

0-10 minutes= call function after every 2 minutes

After 10 minutes
10-30 minutes = call function after every 5 minutes

After that
Call function after every 10 minutes upto 5 hours

Comment: try to have a look at java.util.Timer. It can be done very easily. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify what scheduling system you want,

but if you use quartz then combination of the following two will do the trick:

This will change the cron trigger of the job:

[reschedule a job using quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077939/3942132)

In here you will count the number of invocations,
as this is not enough you will also add an enum of current state, to know on what part of the three you are on:

[count number of invocation using atomic integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25257342/3942132)

```
@Data
public class triggerHourHelper {
    private TaskPart taskPart;
    private AtomicInteger counter;
} 

public enum TaskPart {
   ONE,TWO,THREE
}
```

all you have to do is at the end of the job check if numberOfInvocation => is equal to X(the number indicates we should move to the next part),

simple example(you can use switch case or other more java 8+ ways of achieving this):

```
private boolean shouldReschedule() {
    if(ONE.equals(taskPart)){
        return numberOfInvocation == 5; 
    }
    //else if... 
}
```

Comment: I am using Task Schedular

Comment: @Aman Mate The concept is the same for any framework